# Recursive calls when the condition is doubled

Tags: c++, recursion

Here is the question: This program repeats the if condition twice; how will the recursive calls work inside each if block is what seems a little bit not that simple.

I am trying to understand if the execution from the first recursive call will jump to the second if block or if for every value of c, there will be another two recursive calls because the function has two recursive calls; here the value of the variable c meaning after it is processed inside the function with the subtraction operation.

Thanks to all!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void ex(char c);

void ex(char c) { 
   if (c >'a') { 
       ex(c-1);
   }  

   cout<< c;    

   if (c>'a') { 
     ex(c-1);
   } 
}

int main()
{
   ex('c');
}
```

Comment: you can use a debugger to step through your code line by line

Comment: Why don't you try running the program? If the output doesn't make sense, you can add it to the post.

Comment: Are you aware that the value of `c` is not changed inside `ex` body?

Comment: a recursive call like a non recursive call restart the function from the beginning. If the compiler detect the recursive call is *terminal* the new call is not *embedded* in the stack but replaced by the equivalent of a jump (but still at the beginning). your second recursive call is terminal

Comment: Thanks!! Yes, I understand that the second recursive call may not take place because the second if condition may not be True, so the value of the variable c may not change as well. I thought that the execution of the program just jumps from the first if block to the second if block and that every value of c doesn't create another two additional calls.

Comment: @Sofia190 Look at my answer for more

Comment: SO is so awesome, especially the colours! And I love debuggers! That is such an awesome idea!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A recursive call like a non recursive call, the called function starts from its beginning.

If the compiler detect the recursive call is *terminal* the new call is not *added* in the stack but replaced by the equivalent of a jump (but still going at the beginning except few instructions about the stack management). Your second recursive call is terminal.

You can see the calls using a debugger or modifying your code to have :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void ex(char c, string indent = string()) { 
   cout << indent << "enter with " << c << endl;

   if (c >'a') { 
       ex(c-1, indent + "@");
   }  

   cout<< indent << c << endl;    

   if (c>'a') { 
     ex(c-1, indent + "$");
   } 

   cout << indent << "exit with " << c << endl;
}

int main()
{
   ex('c');
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ a.cc
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
enter with c
@enter with b
@@enter with a
@@a
@@exit with a
@b
@$enter with a
@$a
@$exit with a
@exit with b
c
$enter with b
$@enter with a
$@a
$@exit with a
$b
$$enter with a
$$a
$$exit with a
$exit with b
exit with c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

The deep of the indent is the deep of the recursive call, and @/$ indicates where the calls was

Comment: Thanks again! Your answer is really helpful.

Comment: The more I looked at it, the more useful it became.That was hard, but with your brilliant help I made it through. No way that I could thank you!